# Once localized with .resx files, how to enable client to view entire website in their language?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, localization, translation, globalization

Most of my .resx files are in App_GlobalResources (explicit), and the master pages are in the App_LocalResources in their directories (implicit).  I have to top line in all my pages set to **culture / uiculture - auto**.

Now that my languages are set up, [Nuux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066560/nuux) explained to me how to create a drop-down box and translate that particular page, and this is great -- a lot more than I had.

But what if I want the end-user to see an array of flags on the homepage, so **they can manually opt to view the *entire site* in that language**? Is this a LOT more intricate than what I've already done, or is it just copying and pasting? Is it going to involve creating a directory for each language?  Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code [Developing an ASP.NET page with MasterPage and Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18753/Developing-an-ASP-NET-page-with-MasterPage-and-Loc). Make it fit your need. If you couldn't customize it. I'll try to help you.

**Update**: Ok, let us try this:
Add new class to your project: and overwrite its content with this

```
 Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
 Imports System.Globalization
 Imports System.Threading

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    'MyBase.InitializeCulture()
    If Session("culture") Is Nothing Then
        Session("culture") = "en-US" 'Set default language
    End If
    Dim cult As String = Session("culture")
    Culture = cult
    UICulture = cult

    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Now go to the codebehind of every page you have and change the Inherits clause :

```
 Partial Class _Default
          Inherits BasePage
```

After this point you need to implement the language interface in a master page

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCulture" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"
         runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" runat="server" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

The event in the masterpage codebehind file remains:

```
Protected Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Session("culture") = ddlCulture.SelectedValue
    Response.Redirect(Request.Path)
End Sub
```

Now your website is ready only customize the control I used to your preference.

On thing remaining is that we used Session to store the user selection, however, when the session expires the user is presented with the default language so you may replace the Session with a persistent cookie. First let this idea work, I hope changing to cookie won't be a problem. I just wanted you keep this concept in mind.

Comment: Thanks Nuux.  I'm almost finished with it.  But I can't figure out -- in this article, what do they mean by the basepage?  I did a "find" in my entire solution and I don't have BasePage anywhere.

Comment: add new class to your project and name it BasePage and then every page should inherit from this class

Comment: Yep -- I just did that Nuux.  I put BaseBage.vb and put it in my app_code folder.  I get this error when I run the page:  Error 32 'RequestLanguageChange_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.homepage_master'.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your patience and help, Nuux.  First, I downloaded the files from the link you gave me, and converted them to vb, and that didn't work.  Then, I tried your method, exactly, and that's giving me 103 errors.  I tried to paste what I had in my homepage.master, but it's too long to fit in here.  This is tough work!  I really do appreciate all of the help you've given me, though, and I understand it's frustrating for you because you don't see the files.  I could email them to you if you wanted me to.  But that would be alot of work on your part, Nuux.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm ok if you email me ! nuux14 at gmail dot com

Comment: Wow, thank you Nuux!  My email is in my profile, and there are 3 or 4 files I could zip together.  That's really asking a  lot, though, I understand this.  I don't know where your email is, but I'll keep looking.