# What is a basepage, and if I don't have one, can I create on in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

To allow the client to manually select their own language, I received instructions to install the following in my "**basepage**".  I just have regular .aspx pages and 5 master pages.  I have a Visual Studio 2010 / **vb** / net 4.0 website.  I just created my own class in Visual Studio and put the **BasePage.vb in my app_code folder**.  Am I doing the right thing?

```
  Public Class BasePage
Inherits Page
Private Const m_DefaultCulture As String = "en-GB"

Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    'retrieve culture information from session
    Dim culture__1 As String = Convert.ToString(Session("MyCulture"))

    'check whether a culture is stored in the session
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture__1) Then
        Culture = culture__1
    Else
        Culture = m_DefaultCulture
    End If

    'set culture to current thread
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture__1)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(culture__1)

    'call base class
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Refer your other question in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965927/once-localized-with-resx-files-how-to-enable-client-to-view-entire-website-in/8968658#8968658)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a class called BasePage and derive all your pages from that Page instead of classic ASP.NET Page.

Your BasePage would derive from classic ASP.NET Page.

Read [Using a Custom Base Class for your ASP.NET Pages' Code-Behind Classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Hasan!  I appreciate  your response!  I just did what you told me to do -- I created a class.  Now would I have to put something at the top of my homepage.master or homepage.master.vb file?  Something like Inherits="BasePage"??  Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonWeber Every page in your project must already be deriving from System.Web.UI.Page just replace that with the name of your class. Make sure your custom base does inherit from UI.Page

Comment: Okay -- thank you very much for your help, Hasan -- I'll replace the system.web.ui.page with basepage.  Thanks again!